# Dynamic Hyperlink in a Word template (Dynamics 365)

Tags: templates, ms-word, hyperlink, microsoft-dynamics, crm

I need to insert a dynamic hyperlink into a Dynamics CRM word template.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7SMq.png)

So I have a field that contains a URL, but I can't find a way to use that field as the "href" of the link in the word template.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I tried to insert an hyperlink, alt + F9 and insert the xml mapped field. But when I save and close and open again the field is converted into plain text:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MS05.png)